# Reduzir código que referencia a um mesmo objeto?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-excel

Aqui o código, teria alguma forma de reduzir isso? (Apenas por motivos de aprendizado)

```
worksheet.Row(1).Style.Font.FontColor = ClosedXML.Excel.XLColor.White;
worksheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
worksheet.Row(1).Style.Alignment.SetHorizontal(XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center);
worksheet.Row(1).Style.Alignment.SetVertical(XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center);
worksheet.Row(1).Height = 32;
```

Eu pensei em algo como...

```
worksheet.Row(1)(.Style.Font.FontColor = ClosedXML.Excel.XLColor.White).Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

Mas não funciona :/

Comment: Você está usando esse pacote do nuget: `https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não funciona mesmo e não faz o menor sentido. O máximo que daria para fazer é:

```
var objeto = worksheet.Row(1).Style;
objeto.Font.FontColor = ClosedXML.Excel.XLColor.White;
objeto.Font.Bold = true;
objeto.Alignment.SetHorizontal(XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center);
objeto.Alignment.SetVertical(XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/ExcelFormat.cs).

Obviamente poderia ter um outro objeto sem o `Stype` para pegar o `Height` e também poderia ter um que tivesse junto o `Font` ou o `Aligment`. Mas nem há ganho.

Eu evitaria isso até ter certeza que domina todas consequências. Isso, do jeito que está, sem considerar o contexto, dará certo, mas um exemplo mais complexo pode não funcionar do jeito que espera.

Isso é uma repetição normal que não causa problemas, não é um caso para [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

Comment: Valeu o/! Mas tipo, digamos que eu esteja trabalhando em algo extremamente minucioso no desempenho, fazendo do jeito que você sugeriu, eu ganharia ou perderia?

Comment: Em se tratando de GUI seria irrelevante. Se for uma outra coisa mais minuciosa provavelmente C# é a linguagem errada para fazer isso. Fora isso, teria que medir. Não existem verdades absolutas.

Comment: O amigo @bigown está 100% correto quando diz que a perda de performance é irrelevante. O papa da computação já dizia que passamos 97% do tempo perdendo tempo otimizando o que não é necessário. No caso o objeto não é copiado, apenas uma referência a ele é guardada em memória. Provavelmente o otimizador do C# irá remover a atribuição e colocar tudo **inline**.

Comment: @Loudenvier muito bem observado, inclusive pelo "provavelmente", já que não há grantias, pode até ser mais otimizado por não ter que chamar O `Row()` e o `Style` tantas vezes. Não podemos garantir. Otimização não é algo que você conta com certeza, depende de implementação, pode inclusive mudar no futuro. Por isso eu disse que tem que medir. Em cada caso.